# Visual Studio XAML Designer Error

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, visual-studio-2015

Today I decided to check out the Universal Windows Platform and see how it differs from WPF, but I ran into a problem. When I open the MainPage.xaml file, the designer doesn't load and shows me this:

[image: error message]

I did not change anything in the project since it's been created by Visual Studio. Also, I can compile it and run it with no problems.

Here is the full error:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
The app didn't start. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8027025B)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.HostUtility.AppPackage.AppPackageNativeMethods.IApplicationActivationManager.ActivateApplication(String appUserModelId, String activationContext, ActivateOptions options, Int32& processId)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.HostUtility.AppPackage.DesignerWrtUtility.ActivateApplication(String appUserModelId, String activationContext, Object site, Boolean isRunningElevated)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.ActivateApplicationInternal(String appUserModelId, String activationContext, Object site)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.CreateDesignerProcess(String applicationPath, String clientPort, Uri hostUri, IDictionary environmentVariables, Int32& processId, Object& processData)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.ProcessIsolationDomain..ctor(ProcessDomainFactory factory, IIsolationBoundary boundary, AppDomainSetup appDomainInfo, IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, String baseDirectory)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.CreateIsolationDomain(IIsolationBoundary boundary)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.CreateIsolationDomain(IIsolationBoundary boundary)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.CreateInstance[T](Type type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedObjectFactory.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerHost.Services.VSIsolationService.CreateObjectFactory(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, IObjectCatalog catalog)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolationService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, CancellationToken cancelToken, DesignerServiceEntry& entry, IServiceProvider serviceOverrides)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.IsolatedDesignerView.CreateDesignerViewInfo(CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.InvokeWithCulture[T](CultureInfo culture, Func`2 func, CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.<>c__DisplayClass10_0`1.<StartTask>b__0()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Community on Windows 10.

Comment: Possibly because of this? `The app didn't start.` - check if you have the Universal Windows Platform correctly installed, possibly you're missing something. You may need a full reinstall if this turns into an exercise of finding the needle in a haystack.

Comment: All the Universal Windows App Development Tools seem to be installed. Is there anything else that I need to install? May as well just do a full reinstall.

Comment: So I did a repair in the setup and that didn't help either. May try few more things.

Answer (score 0):

So after looking around the web for a few hours, I found [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/276f8170-21f9-4f2d-a96e-9d4e84d10511/an-unhandled-exception-has-occured-xaml-designer) and the answer at the end by G.Plevne seems to have solved my issue.

Here's the answer for convenience:

> 1. Open Registry Editor using regedit.exe.
> 2. Right click on HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
> 3. Click on "Permissions" and in popup click on "Add".
> 4. In 2nd Popup click on "Advanced".
> 5. In 3rd Popup click on "Find Now".
> 6. In "Search Results" click on "All Application Packages" and then click "Ok".
> 7. Now in 2nd Popup "Select Users or Groups" click again "Ok".
> 8. In Permissions select under Allow "Read" and Click "Ok".
> 9. Close the Registry Editor. No need to restart.